# neural network formula

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, neural-networks

I was interested in communicating a neural network fit that I obtained from R's nnet package in the form of some type of regression equation. The model I obtained gave:

```
a 2-1-1 network with 5 weights
options were - linear output units  decay=1e-05
 b->h1 i1->h1 i2->h1 
 -0.75  17.72   0.85 
 b->o h1->o 
 0.27  0.59
```

Any idea on how to write this in "equation form"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using linear activation functions then you cannot exactly copy your neural network model to a linear regression model. This would be like asking "I have a quadratic model $y=x^2$, how can I use linear regression to make this $y=ax+b$?"

If you want to approximate the neural network outputs with a regression model then you should just create many random inputs, calculate the outputs, and use this set of data to make a linear regression model.

Comment: Yes. That's what I sort of figured too. It's easy to do with linear activation functions (i.e., the identity), but, I don't think R gives the specific form of the sigmoid function used... at least I couldn't find any documentation on it!

Comment: By the way, how would you then, out of curiosity, as you say, "copy your neural network model to a linear regression model."

Comment: @IkjyotSinghKohli The second part of my answer explains how to do that. Just generate inputs and outputs with your neural network and then use that data for linear regression. This will give a linear approximation (which probably won't be good).